# Error launching Hadoop Streaming job

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

I am launching a Hadoop streaming job that fails.  The line that launches it is:

`hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.2.2.5.3-1.jar -conf ~/HADOOP/conf/hadoop-cluster.xml -files aggregation_jobs -input /epcot -output /crowd_analytics/event_count/ -mapper "aggregation_jobs/streaming/event_count_map.py" -reducer "aggregation_jobs/streaming/event_count_reduce.py" -verbose >> output`

The contents of the hadoop-cluster.xml file are these:

`<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
                <value>hdfs://fsdala12080.test.domain.com/</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
                <value>yarn</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
                <value>fsdala12081.test.domain.com:8032</value>
        </property>
</configuration>`

And I get the following error:

`java.net.UnknownHostException: ww-am04035180-010082030080.test.domain.com: ww-am04035180-010082030080.test.domain.com: unknown error
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.Environment.getHost(Environment.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamUtil.<clinit>(StreamUtil.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.setJobConf(StreamJob.java:822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.run(StreamJob.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.HadoopStreaming.main(HadoopStreaming.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ww-am04035180-010082030080.test.domain.com: unknown error
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1479)
    ... 13 more`

where the first part of the unknown host string is my local computer, which is not in the cluster that I am talking too. By the way, I can talk from my computer to the cluster and copy files from my local hard drive to hdfs on that cluster. Any ideas on why this might not be working? Why is it peaking my local host? Any errors on my submission of the job?  Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: What is in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: In my local machine, nothing, only localhost and broadcast host.  On the cluster machines, each cluster machine has all other cluster machines in /etc/hosts

Comment: You should add `198.1.1.1 fsdala12080.test.domain.com` to your local `/etc/hosts` where 198.1.1.1 being actual IP of namenode